# difference between axis and dim keyword arguments

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I know how the keyword argument axis works. However, i also see the keyword argument 'dim' being used in places. example `tf.nn.softmax(logits, dim=-1, name=None)`. Is there any difference between how the two are to be used?

Answer (score 0):

In this particulcar case the difference is quite simple:

"[SOME ARGUMENTS ARE DEPRECATED. They will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: dim is deprecated, use axis instead"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax)